# node.js express app res.download(path, name) doesn't give the correct name while downloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, download

Let's start with what I got:

```
core.app.get('/download/:key', function (req, res) {
    require("./../../module/fileupload.js").download(req.params.key, function(file, filename) {
        console.log(file + " - " + filename);
        if (file != null) res.download(file, filename);
        else res.json({success: false, error: "Unknown download key"});
    });
});
```

I get this console output meaning that it works:

```
uploads\477559c2-1350-4608-b100-40017b13f9e0 - testfile.png
```

But when I try to download it, it gives me this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjLXh.png)

And in the documentation it says this:

> Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers will prompt the user for download. By default, the Content-Disposition header “filename=” parameter is path (this typically appears in the browser dialog). Override this default with the filename parameter.
>   When an error ocurrs or transfer is complete, the method calls the optional callback function fn. This method uses res.sendFile() to transfer the file.
>
> res.download('/report-12345.pdf', 'report.pdf');

Any reasons why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
```

Before calling `res.download()`?

Comment: Still the same result, plus that's what the 2nd argument of `res.download()` does